# StopWords remover in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stop-words

I have a problem in scala. I need to remove stopwords from an RDD[String] txt file.

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val tweetsPath = args(0)
val outputDataset = args(1)

val tweetsRaw: RDD[String] = sc.textFile(tweetsPath)

val stopWords = Array("a","able","about","across","after","all","almost","also","am","among","an","and","any","are","as","at","be","because","been","but","by","can","cannot","could","dear","did","do","does","either","else","ever","every","for","from","get","got","had","has","have","he","her","hers","him","his","how","however","i","if","in","into","is","it","its","just","least","let","like","likely","may","me","might","most","must","my","neither","no","nor","not","of","off","often","on","only","or","other","our","own","rather","said","say","says","she","should","since","so","some","than","that","the","their","them","then","there","these","they","this","tis","to","too","twas","us","wants","was","we","were","what","when","where","which","while","who","whom","why","will","with","would","yet","you","your","ain't","aren't","can't","could've","couldn't","didn't","doesn't","don't","hasn't","he'd","he'll","he's","how'd","how'll","how's","i'd","i'll","i'm","i've","isn't","it's","might've","mightn't","must've","mustn't","shan't","she'd","she'll","she's","should've","shouldn't","that'll","that's","there's","they'd","they'll","they're","they've","wasn't","we'd","we'll","we're","weren't","what'd","what's","when'd","when'll","when's","where'd","where'll","where's","who'd","who'll","who's","why'd","why'll","why's","won't","would've","wouldn't","you'd","you'll","you're","you've")

val cleanTxt = tweetsRaw.
  filter(x => x.startsWith("San Francisco") || x.startsWith("Chicago") || !stopWords.contains(x));

cleanTxt.saveAsTextFile(outputDataset)
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. I must maintain the same structure (using the SparkConf and not moving to a SparkSession). How can I do to pick all the tweets starting with "Chicago" and "San Francisco", removing the stopwords from the text and have as an output the whole tweets line by line without those stopwords ?

I did a flatmap of my tweetsraw but with a flatmap i have as an output only the words without the stop words but what I need is the whole line without the stopwords, not only the words.

I hope that I was clear about what I wanted and that you could help me to resolve this !

Thanks guys.

P.S. I tried many many things with the method StopWordsRemover from the scala library but I just can't figure how to make it work without initializing a SparkSession and doing it with a SparkConf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do to pick all the tweets starting with "Chicago" and "San
> Francisco", removing the stopwords from the text and have as an output
> the whole tweets line by line without those stopwords ?

The following line in your spark script is filtering out the tweets for your conditions. However it is not removing the stop word from the line.

```
val cleanTxt = tweetsRaw.
  filter(x => x.startsWith("San Francisco") || x.startsWith("Chicago") || !stopWords.contains(x));
```

If you want to remove the stop words then you have to use a map transform which would remove the stop words from a line and then you can save it to the file.

Assuming each line represents a tweet that is space delimited , here is what I would do to remove stop words.

```
cleanTxt.map(tweet => tweet.split(" ").filterNot(x => stop.contains(x)).mkString(" ").saveAsTextFile(outputDataset)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! I was so close ! It's hard to find documentation on the net for Scala, i didn't found the "filterNot" and "mkString". Thank you a lot for your advices !

Comment: Cool, here is the link for Scala APIs - https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/
You can also use https://scalafiddle.io/ to test out smaller snippets of code that you can use in transformations. It helps a lot.